# Select multiple images from Photo Gallery on Android using Intents

Tags: java, android, image, gallery

@See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15029515/185022

I`m trying to select images from gallery, but i only found the way to select a single image.

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
```

Is there a way to select multiple images?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379579/select-multiple-images-in-android-gallery see this answer

Comment: You could consider using my project: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12806036/411162

Answer (score 7):

Create a custom gallery same like: [Android custom image gallery with checkbox in grid to select multiple](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/)

Answer (score 6):

First of all you need to use putExtra with your photoPickerIntent

```
photoPickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE);
```

Then in your on activity result you should get ClipData from Intent like this

```
ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
//Where data is param intent of onActivityForResult
```

And iterate this clipData to get URI for specific picked image.

```
for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++){
    Uri uri = clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri();
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE added in API level 18

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE thing. You will receive a set of Uris.

Something like

```
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action))
        && Intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {
        ArrayList<Parcelable> list =
    intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        for (Parcelable parcel : list) {
           Uri uri = (Uri) parcel;
           /// do things here.
       }
    }
```

Saw this code block on a google-groups post. Just try this out.
Thanks.

Comment: @kalpesh Ok, It's like you fire your activity with **Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE**, and should override your **onActivityResult()**, inside which u write the above _code_. I haven't tried out this code yet, as I'm in the middle of something. 

The above code just verifies, if the action is what u fired and it has extra data, then collect the results to an array list.

For further details, see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE).

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I mean willtate's answer is more than enough.

Comment: First thanks for reply. But M sorry I try your code as said by you but this Intent is called to send activity from my device. I am new in android developer So is their possibility of my mistake. At Now i follow the answer of willtake.....

Comment: Sorry my mistake, Send won't let you pick. Forget this.

Comment: It's ok....I think likeaboss answer is also very useful....I think in android all thing is going better when we use it as custom......what's you say...?

Comment: This is the code needed to receive multiple files from the gallery ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE intent, it helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should implement custom gallery for multiple image pick action.

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15029515/1136023) in details.

Comment: but it open all the images,how to open folder vise