# how to launch default android gallery without startActivityForResult

Tags: android, gallery, start-activity

as in the title, but i don't need to return anythimg! just open a gallery.. i tried with

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    startActivity(intent);
```

but i have problem with HTC devices stock gallery... i only need to open a gallery on the device...stock or alternative/downloaded one.

with startActivityForResult return the selected photos, but i don't care... i need that the user can long tap to select multiple photos and than click "share via" command

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create your own Gallery using a GridView and fill the images in, you will have to implement a custom Adapter for that, have a look at [Displaying images from SD Card tutorial](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/displaying-images-sd-card).

Comment: thanks for answering! yes, it's a solution.. but if i want to use an installed gallery? is it possibile? i need 'share via' command..

Comment: You can also implement Share via command through code please refer to this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746661/select-multiple-images-from-photo-gallery-on-android-using-intents

Comment: these are excellent solutions .. but I do not want to add code to my app .. I would just launch the gallery from the app ...is there a solution to this?

Comment: You can do it via the method you mentioned in your question but s you said you are not interested in onActivityResult, also it doesnt let you select multiple files by default, so my best guess is you have to implement your own Gallery, apart from that I do not think there is any other way.

Comment: the code in i've mentioned works fine on my galaxy nexus.. problems happens withc htc devices..with android pure i get no error... and with samsung devices too... I thought maybe my code did not work or is incorrect.. then i ask here on stackoverflow..because with 'startActivity(intent);' app works fine on my device, and i can select multiple photos and tap 'share via' with no errors.. if there isn't any solution i have to change code implementig a custom gallery necessarily.. thanks for answering