# select multiple images in Android Gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery, image-uploading

i m working with one application that have one functionality to select multiple images from android inbuilt `Gallery/Camera` .

Gallery is open successfully using below code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

but i am able to select only One image from Gallery. so please suggest me how to select multiple images from inbuilt gallery .

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: Have you noticed there are at least 2 duplicates of your question on stackoverflow?
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058922/select-multiple-images-using-galleryview)
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746661/select-multiple-images-from-photo-gallery-on-android-using-intents)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i had refer this two link [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746661/select-multiple-images-from-photo-gallery-on-android-using-intents)

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746661/select-multiple-images-from-photo-gallery-on-android-using-intents): [Select Multiple Images Using GalleryView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058922/select-multiple-images-using-galleryview) and [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746661/select-multiple-images-from-photo-gallery-on-android-using-intents)

but not getting Ans for which i m looking for  .. but i have found alternative solution . Get all images from inbuilt Gallery and set it all our custom Gellery .. kindly check out this link [Custom Gallery with checkbox](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/#comment-836)

i hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is an old question, but I guess this might be still useful to somebody.
I just released the source code for my multiple image selection activity. You can find it in the following GitHub repo:

https://github.com/derosa/MultiImageChooser

I hope it's useful for you!

Comment: This one is good solution. Still it needs somewhat improvement as its not a smoother while scrolling down/up.

Comment: @PareshMayani true, but that's related to the thumbnail request method. I'll someday recode it for making it async.

Comment: I did it already :) Will post article for the same on my blog.

Comment: I have a question, how do i integrate this so that its can be started by a startActivityForResult()

Comment: The above link has some issues https://github.com/derosa/MultiImageChooser/issues/1 use this instead https://github.com/derosa/MultiImageChooser/tree/notthemed

Answer (score 1):

```
 Cursor imagecursor1 = managedQuery(
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
    null, orderBy + " DESC");

   this.imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
  imageUrls.size();

   for (int i = 0; i < imagecursor1.getCount(); i++) {
   imagecursor1.moveToPosition(i);
   int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor1
     .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
   imageUrls.add(imagecursor1.getString(dataColumnIndex));
  }

   options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
  .showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_image)
  .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_for_empty_url)
  .cacheInMemory().cacheOnDisc().build();

   imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, imageUrls);

   gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
  gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

You want to more clarifications. http://mylearnandroid.blogspot.in/2014/02/multiple-choose-custom-gallery.html