# select multiple images from gallery and get all the images from onActivity result in android

Tags: android-imageview, android-gridview, android-gallery

In my application I am trying to select multiple images from gallery and I want to move to my folder.

I tried with some example coding its not working properly.

I used android code its getting selecting the multiple images but how to get all the images in onActivity result.

I have tried so far

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setType("image/*");
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 1);
```

How to select these images in OnActivity Result

Then also I tried with [this link](https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick) But its not showing all the images from gallery and after moving its not updating the gallery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9396016/4741246

May be it can help you for select multiple images.

Answer (score 0):

I hope below link is help you

[click here](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-select-multiple-photos-from-gallery/)

Comment: its not showing all the images from gallery, i already tried this

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all images from gallery, try using a MergeCursor, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MergeCursor.html

Use two cursors, one to retrieve image metadata from EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI and another from INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI as follows:

```
Cursor cursor1 = this.context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
Cursor cursor2 = this.context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
MergeCursor cursor = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[]{ cursor1, cursor2 });
```

Refer this code here - https://github.com/ayanami/android-sample/blob/master/image-select-sample/src/com/example/hoge/ImageMediaManager.java