# select multiple images from gallery using startActivityResult

Tags: android

I develop to open camera or gallery to select images how to open gridview  to select multiple images using startActivityResult

Comment: check this ref:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379579/select-multiple-images-in-android-gallery?rq=1

Comment: this lib helpss you a lot https://github.com/lovetuzitong/MultiImageSelector