# In custom gallery, On scrolling images repalcing

Tags: android

I have create a custom gallery for selecting multiple photos in android . I am using AsynTask to set bitmap. When i am scrolling my screen, images replacing with next images and the setting to previous location.

Comment: I follow this code to create the custom gallery....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028496/does-whatsapp-uses-the-native-gallery-while-sharing-images

Comment: Try this : https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i want to use that code only. It's working fine, only on scrolling images replacing frequently.

Comment: hi, I found the solution for it, I just  removed getView and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public class CustomGallery extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

/**
 * Created by Ramesh on 04-Jan-16.
 */

```
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
private String[] arrPath;
private boolean[] thumbnailsSelection;
private int ids[];
private int count;
String imgDecode;
ArrayList<String> imageIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_gallery);


    System.out.println("MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE-->" + MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (Integer.valueOf(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT)>=23) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            Log.i("Permission Log", " Permission Granted----> if cond");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            Log.i("Permission Log", " Permission Granted----> else cond");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
        }
    }

    else{

        final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
    Log.i( MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, "Media Store Images.Media.Data");
    Log.i(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, "Media Store Images.Media_id" );
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC" ;

    Cursor imageCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null,
            orderBy );

    final int image_column_index = imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    imgDecode = imageCursor.getColumnName(image_column_index);
    this.count = imageCursor.getCount();
    this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
    ids = new int[count];
    this.thumbnailsSelection = new boolean[this.count];

    for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
        imageCursor.moveToPosition(i);
        ids[i] = imageCursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        arrPath[i] = imageCursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }

    GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    imageCursor.close();

    final Button selectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectBtn);
    selectBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button cancelBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);
    cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }



}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
                Log.i(" Permission Log", " Permission Granted");
                final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
                Log.i( MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, "Media Store Images.Media.Data");
                Log.i(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, "Media Store Images.Media_id" );
                final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;

    Cursor imageCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null, orderBy);
    //final int image_column_index = imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    final int image_column_index = imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID );

    imgDecode = imageCursor.getColumnName(image_column_index);
    this.count = imageCursor.getCount();
    this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
    ids = new int[count];
    this.thumbnailsSelection = new boolean[this.count];

    for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
        imageCursor.moveToPosition(i);
        ids[i] = imageCursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        arrPath[i] = imageCursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }

    GridView image_grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    image_grid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    imageCursor.close();

    final Button selectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectBtn);
    selectBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button cancelBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);
    cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                Log.i("Permission Log", " else cond");
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}


private void setBitmap(final ImageView iv, final int id) {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            iv.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }.execute();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.selectBtn:
            final int len = thumbnailsSelection.length;

            String selectImages = "";
            int cnt = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (thumbnailsSelection[i]) {
                    cnt++;
                    Log.i("Custom Gallery", "Inside for loop----->");

                    selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i];
                    System.out.println("Array Path--" + arrPath[i]);
                    imageIdList.add(arrPath[i]);

                }

            }

            if (cnt == 0) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select at least one image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (cnt > 5) {


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You can select only 5 images", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            } else {

               // System.out.println("My ListItem -->>" + imageIdList);
               /* Bundle bundel = new Bundle();
                bundel.putStringArrayList("key", imageIdList);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddVehicle.class);
                intent.putExtras(bundel);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();*/

                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                returnIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("image-list", imageIdList);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();

            }
            break;


        case R.id.cancelBtn:
            onBackPressed();
            break;

    }
}


public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ImageAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;


        /*if (convertView == null) {*/

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
       /* } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        } */


        holder.checkbox.setId(position);
        holder.imageview.setId(position);
        holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;

                int id = cb.getId();
                if (thumbnailsSelection[id]) {
                    cb.setChecked(false);
                    System.out.println("if thumbnail selection");
                    thumbnailsSelection[id] = false;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("else thumbnail selection");
                    cb.setChecked(true);
                    thumbnailsSelection[id] = true;
                }
            }
        });

        holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                int id = holder.checkbox.getId();
                if (thumbnailsSelection[id]) {
                    Log.i("Custom Gallery", "if image click----->");

                    holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
                    thumbnailsSelection[id] = false;
                } else {
                    Log.i("Custom Gallery", "if image not clicked----->");

                    holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
                    thumbnailsSelection[id] = true;


                }
            }
        });

        try {

            setBitmap(holder.imageview, ids[position]);


        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Log.i(e.getMessage(), "Exception:");
        }
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsSelection[position]);
        holder.id = position;

        return convertView;
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageview;
    CheckBox checkbox;
    int id;
}
```

}

Comment: This code works fine, even working on android 6.0 API level 23.