# Sending multiple images using Implicit Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, email-attachments, intentfilter

i'm trying to send multiple images from my DIRECTORY_PICTURES , using intents..
i have written the following code.. but when i click the button, it says "Unfortunately stopped"..i tried debugging, but haven't been able to.. any suggestions ??

```
case R.id.button5:
        File pictures = Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        String[] listofpics = pictures.list();
        Uri uri = null;
        ArrayList <Uri> arraylist = new ArrayList<Uri>(); 
        for(String picture : listofpics){
            uri = Uri.parse("file://" + pictures.toString() + "/" + picture);
            arraylist.add(uri);
        }

        i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        i.setType("image/*");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, arraylist);
        chooser = Intent.createChooser(i, "Send Images : ");
        startActivity(chooser);
        break;
    }
```

P.S. I tried putting the permissions as well..but still didnt work..

```
>                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
>                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
>                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Logcat :

```
11-23 14:07:53.490: E/AndroidRuntime(12264): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-23 14:07:53.490: E/AndroidRuntime(12264): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-23 14:07:53.490: E/AndroidRuntime(12264):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
11-23 14:07:53.490: E/AndroidRuntime(12264):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
11-23 14:07:53.490: E/AndroidRuntime(12264):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
11-23 14:07:53.490: E/AndroidRuntime(12264):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-23 14:07:53.490: E/AndroidRuntime(12264):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-23 14:07:53.490: E/AndroidRuntime(12264):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-23 14:07:53.490: E/AndroidRuntime(12264):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-23 14:07:53.490: E/AndroidRuntime(12264):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 14:07:53.490: E/AndroidRuntime(12264):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-23 14:07:53.490: E/AndroidRuntime(12264):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-23 14:07:53.490: E/AndroidRuntime(12264):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-23 14:07:53.490: E/AndroidRuntime(12264):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-23 14:07:53.490: E/AndroidRuntime(12264): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-23 14:07:53.490: E/AndroidRuntime(12264):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 14:07:53.490: E/AndroidRuntime(12264):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-23 14:07:53.490: E/AndroidRuntime(12264):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
11-23 14:07:53.490: E/AndroidRuntime(12264):    ... 11 more
11-23 14:07:53.490: E/AndroidRuntime(12264): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-23 14:07:53.490: E/AndroidRuntime(12264):    at com.example.interviewprep.Intents.launchStuff(Intents.java:80)
11-23 14:07:53.490: E/AndroidRuntime(12264):    ... 14 more
```

thanks !

Comment: i've edited it..please check..

Comment: there is issue with ur declaration of R.id.button5:

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send Images"
        android:onClick="launchStuff" />
this is all i have done.. for button5..
i just put a tast in that button5, and it worked fine actually..
any other advice ?

Comment: inside case R.id.button5: just comment all code and just print a toast there and tel me if it crashed or not

Comment: i just put a toast, and it didnt crash..

Comment: ohh can u tell me what code is wriiten at this line ?-->com.example.interviewprep.Intents.launchStuff(Intents.java:80)

Comment: line 80 : for(String picture : listofpics)

Comment: So `listofpics` is null. Add to your code `if (listofpics==null){Toast(... pictures.getAbsolutePath() ... does not contain files...); return}`. But still better check first if the directory exits. `if(!pictures.exists()){Toast(...); return;}`.

Comment: yes i did.. i had a folder already in my phone memory called Pictures, with images in it. i dont know the reason, why it wasn't getting picked from there..
I just copied that folder(Pictures) into my SDCard and it worked..
and i used the same permissions i mentioned above.. 
Thanks for your time everyone !

Answer (score 0):

you can try using this links for guiding your way :

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746661/select-multiple-images-from-photo-gallery-on-android-using-intents)  - look on accepted answer.

1: [Select Multiple Images Using GalleryView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058922/select-multiple-images-using-galleryview) and [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746661/select-multiple-images-from-photo-gallery-on-android-using-intents)

but not getting Ans for which i m looking for .. but i have found alternative solution . Get all images from inbuilt Gallery and set it all our custom Gellery .. kindly check out this [linkCustom Gallery with](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/#comment-836)   checkbox

i hope it will help you.

Credit to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379579/select-multiple-images-in-android-gallery) post

Comment: Appreciate your response and thanks for those links.. but i'm still not getting what did i do wrong..

Comment: you cannot send multiple / get images via android normal intents.. (if i remember right), thats why you need to use alternative option.